# probability gsce maths box of sweets question

Tags: probability

a box of sweets contains only caramels, rum truffles and mints ben chooses a sweet at random 
the probability that he chooses a caramel is 0.4
 the probability that he chooses a rum truffle is 0.15 
calculate the probability that ben chooses a mint

Comment: Between this and your other recent questions, it looks like you are just posting homework problems here for us to do for you.  These are very basic questions...please show what you have tried and where you have gotten stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible things he can choose, and the probabilities must sum to $1$.

If $x$ is the probability that he chooses a mint, then we have

$$1 = 0.4 + 0.15 + x,$$

which implies $x=0.45$.

Having said that, keep in mind that MSE isn't intended to be a homework site and that you're expected to have shown at least some effort to answer your own questions.